# Fullcalendar eventClickLimit not showing custom popover and throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm getting an error when trying to show a bootstrap popover after a eventClickLimit event occurs in FullCalendar. The error says "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'documentElement' of undefined or null reference" on this line

> $(this).popover('show');

Here is my code for the fullcalendar that shows the eventClickLimit event code that tries to show a popover.
NOTE - My dayClick shows a popover ok, it's just the eventClickLimit that doesn't. Maybe something in the click event code isn't correct.

```js
$('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next', //today',
            center: 'title',
            //right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            right: ''
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        selectable: true,
        slotMinutes: 15,
        eventLimit: 1,
        //eventLimit: true, // for all non-agenda views
        //views: {
        //    agenda: {
        //        eventLimit: 2 // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
        //    }
        //},
        events: '/ManageSpaces/GetDiaryEvents/',

        eventLimitClick: function (cellInfo, jsEvent) {
            //var s = cellInfo.segs;
            $(this).popover({
                html: true,
                placement: 'bottom',
                //container: 'body',
                title: function () {
                    return $("#events-popover-head").html();
                },
                content: function () {
                    return $("#events-popover-content").html();
                }
            });
            //$(this).popover('toggle');
            //if ($calPopOver)
            //    $calPopOver.popover('destroy');
            //$calPopOver = $(this).popover('show');
            $(this).popover('show');
        },
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) { //function (data, event, view) {
            //var s = cellInfo.segs;
            $("#eventDetails.collapse").collapse('toggle');

            if ($calPopOver)
                $calPopOver.popover('destroy');
        },
        dayClick: function (data, event, view) {
            $(this).popover({
                html: true,
                placement: 'bottom',
                container: 'body',
                title: function () {
                    return $("#day-popover-head").html();
                },
                content: function () {
                    return $("#day-popover-content").html();
                }
            });
            $(this).popover('toggle');
            if ($calPopOver)
                $calPopOver.popover('destroy');
            $calPopOver = $(this).popover('show');
        }
    });
```

```html
<div id="eventcalendar">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div id='fullcalendar' style="width:100%"></div>
                <div id="day-popover-head" class="hide">Add Event</div>
                <div id="day-popover-content" class="hide">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="test" value="test" />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="events-popover-head" class="hide">Events</div>
                <div id="events-popover-content" class="hide">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="test" value="test" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="eventDetails" class="col-md-2 collapse" style="background-color:yellow;">
                hello
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?